# How can I get at to work on OSX?

Tags: osx, cron, at

My `at` on Mac OS X 10.11 seems to be incapable of launching jobs. I tried:

```
echo "date > foo" | at now
```

Running `atq` afterwards shows the job queued and no file `foo` was created. To make sure the problem isn't a date mixup, I ran:

```
$ date && echo "date > foo" |  at now && atq
```

And both `date` and `atq` showed the same time.

I also checked for `at.allow` and `at.deny` files. `/usr/lib/cron/at.deny` exists but is empty and `/usr/lib/cron/at.allow` doesn't exist. According to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/at.1.html), that means that I am allowed to run it:

```
If _PERM_PATH/at.allow does not exist, _PERM_PATH/at.deny is checked,
every username not mentioned in it is then allowed to use at.

[...]

FILES
   _PERM_PATH/at.allow   allow permission control (/usr/lib/cron/at.allow)
   _PERM_PATH/at.deny    deny permission control (/usr/lib/cron/at.deny)
```

What am I doing wrong/what can I do to schedule this for later?

Comment: script.sh must contain internal bug, and about direct tries you should try: echo "$PROGRAM < input > output" | at now + 1 minute

Comment: This doesn't give any output file for me when I tried it. I even tried replacing $PROGRAM with the actual path.

Comment: @Christopher it's not supposed to give output. It should show a message like `job 3 at Fri Dec  4 18:21:00 2015` but that's printed to stderr, you won't see it if you're redirecting output. Also, please [edit] and tell us your operating system. Ideally, also try with something simple like `echo "date > file" | at now +1 minute` and check whether anything is printed to `file`.

Comment: @Christopher , nice test, i am confirming that ... echo "date > foo" | at now ; sleep 1 ; cat foo ... works well on all my linux comps.

Comment: Related (and up-to-date for macOS Mojave): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478823/making-at-work-on-macos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the `at` command doesn't work out of the box.

In my test, for example:

- OS X, according to [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working) needs:

  ```
    sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
  ```
- raspbian needed:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install at (which will install and run atd, at daemon)
  ```
- Arch Linux had `at` installed, but again needed the daemon to be started manually:

  ```
    sudo systemctl start atd
    sudo systemctl enable atd
  ```