# Making "at" work on macOS

Tags: centos, osx, at

I am working on a CentOS server and schedule a task with command `at`

```
# echo "touch a_long_file_name_file.txt" | at now + 1 minute
job 2 at Wed Oct 31 13:52:00 2018
```

One minute later,

```
# ls | grep a_long_file_name_file.tx
a_long_file_name_file.txt
```

the file was successful created.

However, if I run it locally on my macOS,

```
$ echo "touch a_long_file_name_file.txt" | at now + 1 minute
job 31 at Wed Oct 31 13:58:00 2018
```

Minutes later, if it failed to make such a file.

I checked the version of `at` on the CentOS server

```
AUTHOR:  
At was mostly written by Thomas Koenig, ig25@rz.uni-karlsruhe.de.  
2009-11-14
```

In contrast, the macOS version

```
AUTHORS
     At was mostly written by Thomas Koenig <ig25@rz.uni-karlsruhe.de>.  The time parsing routines are
     by
     David Parsons <orc@pell.chi.il.us>, with minor enhancements by
     Joe Halpin <joe.halpin@attbi.com>.

BSD                            January 13, 2002
```

I found that `at`, `atq`, `atrm` are not of GNU coreutils.

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ | grep at
cat
date
pathchk
realpath
stat
truncate
```

How could I install the latest version of `at` on macOS and make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install the latest version of GNU at?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478633/install-the-latest-version-of-gnu-at)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use \`at\` to schedule a script to execute on macOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407181/how-do-i-use-at-to-schedule-a-script-to-execute-on-macos)

Comment: `at`, `cron`, and `periodic` are "deprecated": https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: @Christopher: that Apple page indeed says that `at` is "deprectaed", but does not explain how to run a job once "in x minutes".

Comment: @mivk Use a LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of updating `at` and the associated tools on macOS, lets try to make the default `at` on macOS work.

The `at` manual on macOS says (my emphasis):

> IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
>
> Note that `at` is implemented through the `launchd(8)` daemon periodically invoking `atrun(8)`, **which is disabled by default**.  See `atrun(8)` for information about enabling `atrun`.

Checking the `atrun` manual:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `atrun` utility runs commands queued by `at(1)`.  It is invoked periodically by `launchd(8)` as specified in the `com.apple.atrun.plist` property list.  By default the property list contains the Disabled
>        key set to true, so `atrun` is never invoked.
>
> Execute the following command as root to enable `atrun`:
>
> ```
> launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
> ```

What I think may be happening here, and what is prompting your other `at`-related questions, is that you just haven't enabled `atrun` on your macOS installation.

On macOS Mojave, in addition to running the above `launchctl` command (with `sudo`), you will also have to add `/usr/libexec/atrun` to the list of commands/applications that have "Full Disk Access" in the "Security & Privacy" preferences on the system.  Note that I don't know the security implications of doing this.  Personally, I have also added `/usr/sbin/cron` there to get cron jobs to work (not shown in the screenshot below as this is from another computer).

[image]

To add a command from the `/usr` path (which won't show up in the file selection dialog on macOS), press <kbd>Cmd+Shift+G</kbd> when the file selection dialog is open (after pressing the plus-icon/button in the bottom of the window).

You do not need to reboot the machine after these changes. I have tested this on macOS Mojave 14.10.1.

Comment: Seems to work in 11.0 / Big Sur also, should others be looking in the future.

Comment: Excellent instructions. Worked for me on 10.15.7 / Catalina. The "Full Disk Access" was the gotcha for me.

Comment: That security setting is a real gotcha! Especially since older answers to the same question do not include it (as, presumably, it was not needed on older OSXes).

Comment: After doing all this, I had to output the result of my command to a file to see the results, in that file. I couldn't see the results in the standard output for some reasons.

Comment: In Big Sur you will find it under `/usr/libexec/atrun`

Comment: @AkhilRaj: This is expected. From the at(1) man page: "The user will be mailed standard error and standard output ..."

Answer (score 2):

To add to Kusalananda correct answer, Adding terminal application to the list of applications that have "Full disk access" will cause the standard output of at jobs to be mailed to the user.

I'm sorry I couldn't comment on his answer. I registered to the site just to add the information above and I don't have permission to comment