# OSX: at requires GUI confirmation

Tags: osx, at

I did as per the instructions in [Making "at" work on macOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478823/31443) (see also [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/43678/98857))

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

to enable [`at`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/at/) on `macos` and now

```
echo 'date > ~/at-date' | at 1
```

works, but only if I click `OK` on this scary dialog that pops up after I hit `return`:

[image: gui confirmation]

If I click `Don't Allow`, I get

> at: cannot open lockfile /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile: Operation not permitted

The effect of the GUI answer persists for a few minutes (i.e., I am not asked the question and `at` either works right away or fails right away).

**How do I make the `"OK"` answer (1)*permanent* and (2)*for all apps*?**

**PS** When I run `at` from `Python` using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), I *always* get the `.lockfile` error, and I am never asked the GUI question.

Comment: @Christopher: `at` and `cron` are venerable tools available on all unix-like systems. I see no reason to switch to a mac-specific functionality.

Comment: See  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: @Christopher: so, instead of a simple command line, I now need to create an XML file?!